# ModBus Timeout Error

Tags: microcontroller, pic, embedded, rs485, modbus

Anyone very experienced with Modbus & RS-485???

My task is to control a DC motor using micro PIC24.
The motor setting like the angle, delay, start/stop, duty cycle, etc will be sent from PC using Modbus to PIC24.

The system is like this:

PIC24 -> UART -> IC MAX3471 -> RS-485 to RJ-45 converter -> RJ-45 to USB -> PC (running modbuspoll tool)

The Modbus format used is Modbus RTU.

At first, the Modbus read holding register function and write single register function is working. But after I send some of the motor settings using Modbus write single register function then the motor start running, it was then the Modbus communication always timeout error.

And once the timeout error happens, the next time I turn on the system again it will keep giving timeout error.
[image]
I've tried changed UART baud rate from 9600 to 115200.
Try changing the RS-485 to RJ-45 converter board (just in case it broke), the phenomena just repeat.

Can someone give me some advice on what could be the possible cause?

Also, I'm not sure about this, in Modbus RTU format, at the start and end there should be 28 bit (at least 3 1/2 character length), but should the micro firmware code care about this since at the PC use modbuspoll tool?

I've tapping the A & B signal using logic analyzer, if I send some character from uC to RS-485 (but not connected to PC), the character showing correctly on A & B line. But if I tapping the A & B line signal when I send read holding register function from PC using modbus poll (give timeout error) I got some weird signal:

[image]

So it seems the problem is not in the uC firmware code, but rather either one of them: USB to RS-485 converter, straight ethernet cable, or RS-485 interface board.
Here's the USB to RS-485 converter that I used:
[image]

and the RS-485 interface board:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In some cases staring a motor or any high-power devices generate noise on grounding signal. If you don't have good chassis ground and shielding this affects your signal.

for debugging:
1) run your controller without heavy load, just check controller with a led or any small load, after setting that led on/ off, if you have a problem then you have a **problem with code and implementation**.

2) if you don't have a problem in the first step, **you should check the grounding and chassis ground**

**recommendation**:  if you work with high voltage load, for safety it's better to use an isolated USB_to_485 module.

Comment: I too more suspecting the hardware problem rather than firmware code. Because the modbus has no communication problem if using USB to serial module (FT232R).

Comment: How do I make the chassis grounded in a good way? Should I just twist a cable at the screw and connect it to my power supply ground?

Comment: @Qrenz what is your motor type? for instance, Cut the length of the wire

Comment: @M KS: brushless DC motor with gearbox 12 V, diameter shaft 28 mm. Good idea, I'll try it.

Comment: Rather, you should _not_ ground the RS-485 signal ground directly against the chassis. That grounding should be much earlier down the line, where the supply ground enters the sub-system. In case of shielding though, it should be grounded against chassis in one end of the wire.

Comment: @Qrenz I think, The problem will be solved, If you use an isolated USB_to_serial. Shielding and grounding have many tricks and relies on your circuit configuration and power distribution mechanism.

Comment: Today I just modified/improved my UART firmware code so have better buffering and data overrun handling. But it still give timeout error...
The project deadline is at the end november...

Comment: I'm still wondering why modbus running very smooth when I just using FT232R breakout board, but keep giving timeout error when using RS-485?

Comment: @Qrenz IS Ft232 base USB_to_485 works but the other not?

Comment: @M KS:
This is working very smooth:
uC(modbus code) - UART1 (Tx Rx Gnd) - FT232R breakout board - USB cable - PC (modbus poll)

But this always timeout error:
uC(modbus code) - UART2 (Tx Rx EN Gnd 3.3V) - MAX3471 (on same board with uC) - 6 cables (A B TxLED RxLED Gnd 3.3V) - RS-485 to RJ-45 board - ethernet cable straight - RJ-45 to USB converter cable - PC (modbus poll).


The proj manager want to use RS-485 ethernet since he plan to control more than 1 device in future, he doesn't want to use USB to serial. And this proj was actually leftover from former employee, I'm continuing it.

Comment: @Qrenz What is the chip inside (RJ-45 to USB converter cable) ? Is that FT232 based system? If you have scope, check the direction control pin on the microcontroller side. delay in control pin may damage the modbus packet

Comment: @M KS The chip is FTDI based when I look at the installed driver at device manager. You mean the enable pin for MAX3471 to change from output to input and vice versa? For now I put a 2 us delay to change from receive to transmit and vice versa, is that enough? I only have a logic analyzer (saleae), I plan to tap the A & B signal tomorrow to see (because if I remember correctly I never seen the LED on RJ-45 port blink). Also  I just saw in MAX3471 datasheet data rate fMAX is 64 kbps, and my UART baud was set to 115200, maybe I should lower it to 9600 bps?

Comment: @Qrenz fMAX is minimum 64K, this is not the problem, some RJ-45 has an ohmic connection!  Check RX and TX and Dir control with a logic analyzer.

Comment: @M KS I've checked the A & B signal of RS-485 using logic analyzer, if I send some character from micro then it's ok the character showing correctly on the line, but the problem is the data that was send from the PC side, it show incorrectly on the line... (I've edited my top question)